# How to C# text/language analysis for detecting address, phone numbers, events etc in a given text?

Tags: c#, .net, text, analysis

Where can I find information on detecting address, phone numbers, events etc in text or email body using C#/.Net
What I am interested in knowing is how products like gmail performs these tasks? if there is a time specified in email body, gmail suggests to create an event!

Answer (score 3):

This would be a good reason to use a few different regular expressions. Using regular expressions would allow you to throw different address, phone number, and date patterns at a block of text and match up the content you're looking for.

**MSDN - RegEx**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx

**C# Regular Expression Cheat Sheet**

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet

**RegExLib**

http://regexlib.com/